# Python function that iterates a menu of three lists of strings issues

Tags: python, function

I have to write a function that takes three dishes and an ingredient and outputs true if the ingredient isn't in the dish and false if any of the dishes contain the ingredient.

I've been trying this for hours and initially was having an issue where it was either outputting true or false for all test cases regardless. I have now tried using any() but its returning a TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable and I'm getting really confused and frustrated.

any advice would be much appreciated.

```
def free_from(menu: list, ingredient: str):
    """Return whether ingredient is in dish.
    
    Preconditions: menu = dish1, dish2, dish3
    Postconditions: if menu has ingredient = false else true
    """
    for dish in menu:
        if any(ingredient in menu):
            return False
    return True

menu = [
         ['soup','onion','potato','leek','celery'],
         ['pizza','bread','tomato','cheese','cheese'],
         ['banana']
       ]
```

Comment: Try without `any`. Example:  `if ingredient in dish:`

Comment: `return all(ingredient not in dish for dish in menu)`…?

Comment: that's what I had initially but it was just returning with true or false on all test cases.

Comment: It's unclear whether the `menu` argument to the function is identical to the `menu` variable outside the function. Is it going to be a *list of strings*, or a *list of list of strings*?

Comment: @MollieMoo Note I edited my comment. You are not using `dish` in your test.

Comment: the menu is a list of three dishes, a dish is represented by a list of strings.

Comment: @deceze, that works for the test cases where True is the answer, but the False ones show up as true as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for dish in menu:
    if ingredient in dish:
        return False
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have another for function that loops through each element in each dish in the menu to check if the specified unwanted ingredient is in the menu.

```
    def free_from(menu: list, unwanted_ingredient: str):
        for dish in menu:
            for ingredient in dish:
                if ingredient == unwanted_ingredient:
                    return False
        return True
    
    menu = [
             ['soup','onion','potato','leek','celery'],
             ['pizza','bread','tomato','cheese','cheese'],
             ['banana']
           ]
    
    print(free_from(menu, 'onion')) # yes onion in menu
    print(free_from(menu, 'garlic')) # no garlic in menu
```

Answer (score 0):

as others have said: `if ingredient in dish:` not menu

I also added some tests:

```py
def free_from(menu: list, ingredient: str):
    """Return whether ingredient is in dish.

    Preconditions: menu = dish1, dish2, dish3
    Postconditions: if menu has ingredient = false else true
    """
    for dish in menu:
        if ingredient in dish:
            return False
    return True


menu = [
    ['soup', 'onion', 'potato', 'leek', 'celery'],
    ['pizza', 'bread', 'tomato', 'cheese', 'cheese'],
    ['banana']
]

testIngredients = ["soup", "banana", "cake", "turkey", "cheese"]
expected = [False, False, True, True, False]
output = []
for ingredient in testIngredients:
    output.append(free_from(menu, ingredient))
print(expected)
print(output)
print(output == expected)
```

output:

```py
[False, False, True, True, False]  
[False, False, True, True, False]  
True
```